# matplotlib with multiple scales showing only one plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm using the function below to plot three lines with two different scales.

```
def plot2(x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3):
    fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
    ax1.plot(x1, y1, 'b')
    ax1.plot(x2, y2, 'g')

    ax2 = ax1.twinx()
    ax2.plot(x3, y3, 'r')

    fig.tight_layout()
    plt.show()
```

However, `ax2` is shadowing ax1 in the plot.

Comment: The function works as expected. What does shadowing mean?

Comment: I can only see the second plot, ax2. I get to see ax1 only if I comment ax2.

Comment: Ok, so you need to provide a [mcve] and the resulting image.

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce the problem. By extending the code to a minimal running example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def plot2(x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3):
    fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
    ax1.plot(x1, y1, 'b')
    ax1.plot(x2, y2, 'g')

    ax2 = ax1.twinx()
    ax2.plot(x3, y3, 'r')

    fig.tight_layout()
    plt.show()

x1 = [1,2,3,4,5] 
x2 = [1.25,2.25,3.25,4.25,5.25]
x3 = [1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5, 5.5]

y1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
y2 = [6,7,8,9,10]
y3 = [11,12,13,14,15]

plot2(x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3)
```

I get the following result:

[png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VF5FJ.png)